# how to get second last element using java script

Tags: javascript

I have a drop down of 7 options. I need to get the  value of second last option using java script. I wrote something but it is not working .

```
$('.checkbox4').on('click', function(e) {
    var last_chekbox4 = $('.checkbox4:last.prev()');
    if (last_chekbox4.is(':checked')) {
        $('.checkbox4').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: all checkboxes are siblings if they are in the same container. @Apurba : can you please show your html?

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors or maybe used `console.log(last_chekbox4)` to make sure you're targeting the correct element?

Answer (score 1):

Use `prev()` method

```
$('.checkbox4:last').prev()
```

If there is some other element in between then use

```
$('.checkbox4:last').prevAll('.checkbox4').first()
```

**FYI :** Above methods don't work if elements are not siblings.

---

**UPDATE :**
Or get the last within the collection which excluded the last one using `:not()` and jQuery `:last`.

```
$('.checkbox4:not(:last):last')
```

Or by the index  using `eq()` method.

```
var $col = $('.checkbox4');
// get element by index, where index starts from 0
var $ele = $col.eq($col.length - 2);
```

Comment: @Pranav C  Is this only working, if all checkboxes in the same container (eg div) ?

Comment: @Mic : nop but it will only get the last one

Comment: @Mic : but it may fails if both elements are not siblings.... in that case second approach needs to use

Answer (score 0):

You have 7 elements. Use `nth-of-type` selector

```
$(".checkbox4:nth-of-type(6)");
```

To select the second last `option`